# iOS - CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations not being called in background

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, core-location, cllocationmanager

I want my iOS app to update it's location when closed and make post requests but location manager `didUpdateLocations` doesn't get called from the background despite it working fine in normal app use. Below is my SendLocation class. Calling `determineCurrentLocation()` get it going.

My problem is that if I call `determineCurrentLocation()` from another class while the app is running - it works perfectly. But when I call it from the App `Delegate didUpdateLocations` never gets called.

```
class SendLocation:  NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{


var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()


struct LocationStruct{
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees?, longitude:CLLocationDegrees?

}

var locationStruct = LocationStruct()
var userLocation: CLLocation? = nil

func sendLocationPost(){
   // This function makes the POST
}


func determineCurrentLocation(){

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=true
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()


    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            print("test1") // This prints fine from background
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }   
    }    
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    print("test2") // This never gets printed from backgrounf
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    locationStruct.latitude=userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
    locationStruct.longitude=userLocation?.coordinate.longitude


    sendLocationPost()


}
```

Below are the two functions I edited in my App Delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let sendLocation = SendLocation()

    sendLocation.determineCurrentLocation()
}
```

My Info.plist has been changed to be correct, as far as I know.

Here is a picture of my Background Modes

[image]

And my privacy settings

[image]

Just in case I'm missing something there.

If anyone has any ideas what I've done wrong then I'd be very appreciative of some help.

Comment: You are allocating your instance of `SendLocation` as a local variable, so it will be released as soon as `applicationDidEnterBackground` returns. Starting location updates when your app is already in the background is too late for long-term background location monitoring anyway; location updates will stop after a few minutes if you do this

Comment: Thanks that fixed the initial problem of the function not being called. Care to elaborate on why it is to late to start updating locations? Maybe you know a better way of doing things?

Comment: You need to start updating location when your app is in the foreground or you can start significant location change monitoring in the foreground Andre then start full location updates when your app is in the background.

Comment: The first time that determineCurrentLocation() is called is on the first ViewController of the app which is in the foreground. Is that not enough? I'm using the same method for foreground and background updating.

Comment: You need to ensure that a single instance of `SendLocation` is used for the entire lifetime of your app. If you create a new instance when you enter the background then you will not get the long term background updates.

Comment: Would using a global variable/singleton from my SendLocation be a good option?